# How to add an object to the screen via the add button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't understand how to add an object via a button to the screen with goods.

**I already have a product listing:**
[image: Product Listing]

When I click on any of the products, I open the product information (conditionally) via .sheet, and then there are two buttons, close and add. [image: Product Sheet] close works, but I need to understand how to implement so that via add button the product is added to the view with Row style product display. Row of goods I have already created, there is CarManager logic:

```
import Foundation

class CartManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var products: [Product] = []
    
    func addToCart(product: Product) {
        products.append(product)
    }
    
    func removeFromCart(product: Product) {
        products = products.filter { $0.id != product.id }
    }
}
```

Here is the code itself, which is responsible for the .sheet when clicking on the product from the listing:

```
struct ProductDetailSheet: View {
    
    
    let product: Product
    @Binding var isSheetPresented: Product?
    @State private var amount = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                Image(product.image)
                Spacer()
                Text(product.name)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(200)])
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            }
            HStack{
                Button("Close") {
                    isSheetPresented = nil
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Add") {
                    isSheetPresented = nil
                }
                Spacer()
                Stepper("Enter an amount: \(amount)", value: $amount, in: 0...200)
              
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    PackingList()
}
```

Here is a piece of code of View with Row style product:

```
  import SwiftUI
    
    struct ProductRow: View {
        
        var product: Product
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image(product.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 50)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Text(product.name)
                        .bold()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.835))
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    
    #Preview {
        ProductRow(product: productRaid[0])
    }
```

And I need to pass the product to this screen when I click on the .add button from the .sheet from the listing view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Recommended: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("1")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
}

#Preview {
    Recommended()
}
```

How do I implement this? Which way to dig? I will be highly grateful to anyone who can share information on how I can implement this.

It should look like this on the screen.
[image]

Full code PackingList

```
import SwiftUI

struct PackingList: View {
    
    @StateObject var cartManager = CartManager()
    
    @State private var selectedProduct: Product? = nil
  
    
    var columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150), spacing: 20)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(productRaid, id: \.id)
                    { product in
                        ProductCard(product: product)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedProduct = product
                            }
                            .sheet(item: $selectedProduct) { product in
                                ProductDetailSheet(product: product, isSheetPresented: $selectedProduct)
                                    .environmentObject(cartManager)
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Hello"))
        }
    }
}

struct ProductDetailSheet: View {
    
    
    let product: Product
    @Binding var isSheetPresented: Product?
    @State private var amount = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack {
                Image(product.image)
                Spacer()
                Text(product.name)
                    .presentationDetents([.height(200)])
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            }
            HStack{
                Button("Close") {
                    isSheetPresented = nil
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Add") {
                    isSheetPresented = nil
                }
                Spacer()
                Stepper("Enter an amount: \(amount)", value: $amount, in: 0...200)
              
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    PackingList()
}
```

The view where the product should be displayed in the row style

```
import SwiftUI

struct Recommended: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var cartManager: CartManager
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(cartManager.products, id: \.id) {
                product in
                ProductRow(product: product)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Your cart total is")
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Recommended()
        .environmentObject(CartManager())
}
```

Comment: You need to add the product in the array of product of the object representing your cart.

Comment: I have it all, I need to figure out how to code to send the data in the button from .sheet to the screen with the product itself displayed.

Comment: You have to pass the cart manager object to subview as ObservedObject or on an EnvironmentObject. The button action will just call the required method of the cart manager.

Comment: Still don't understand how to do it, it's hard to give, maybe there are some guides or lessons on the Internet, where they tell about it in detail?
I tried to find out from chatGPT, he offers me a lot of bullshit, nothing works.

Comment: I've added the full code in the question description, can you give me a hint on how to do it all correctly?

Comment: Have you tried adding objectWillChange.send() in your addToCart function before calling the add function?

Comment: Just add "@EnvironmentObject var cartManager: CartManager" in your ProductDetailSheet, and the call the call to cartManager.addToCart in the add button action